# How can I implement a pop machine instruction on cpu simulator?

Tags: assembly, stack, cpu-architecture

I'm working on a stack memory for cpu sim. I have implemented the push instruction for the stack. Its a wombat 1 machine but I have added hardware modules such as SPR which is the stack pointer register and Ram which is the stack. And also added micro instructions for incrementing the stack when a data is pushed plus another microinstruction for writing the pushed data into the stack which is from the memory data register (mdr->stack[SPR]). So the implementation for the push instructions is:
acc->mdr
mrd->stack[SPR]
SPR increment
End

So my question is what other microinstructions should I add in order to implement the pop instructions and how would the instruction implementation look like?

Comment: spr decrement, read the stack[spr]

Comment: Doesn't your machine have RAM for normal data accesses? I would have expected `mem[SPR]`, not `stack[SPR]`.  Also, I guess your microinstruction has SPR built-in as an implicit operand; otherwise SPR could just be a normal operand to a store microinstruction.

Comment: stack[SPR] is just a name given for the process of writing the data from the mdr to the stack the name mem[SPR] could mean the same thing. Yes sorry for the confusion RAM i referred to above is just a memory so what I mean is theres a main memory that my machine initially have and then I added the Stack mem. And yes I have created an SPR which is the stack pointer register of 16 bits.

Comment: By the way just give me the implementation for pop machine instruction if you can that would be more easier for me to work from.

Comment: Oh sorry haven't seen you answer. My machine doesn't have spr decrement so how can I create a decrement for spr?

Comment: Need no further explanations my friend I have implemented the pop from your answer above already thank you very much